# Finding the best method for recalling unsorted data

Tags: c, malloc

Let us use this basic example code I made below for the question...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VEHICLES 5

typedef struct Car {
   int year;
   char *make;
   char *model;
} Car;

void freeCars (Car **cars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < VEHICLES; i++) free (cars[i]);
    free (cars);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    Car **cars = (Car**) malloc (sizeof (Car*) * VEHICLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < VEHICLES; i++) {
        cars [i] = (Car*) malloc (sizeof (Car));
    }
    // The rest of the code doesn't need to necessarily be known at this given point in time.
    freeCars (cars);
    printf ("Thank you!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The data will be read in from a file that contains it using formatted fscanf statements. I will be running several sorts on the data, and I need to have the original unsorted data accessible. I know that I can copy the information into a second array to preserve it, or completely re-read the contents of the file back into the array. Is one method of sorting objectively better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sorting won't change the content of `Car`s, you can just copy the references.

```
Car **cars_cpy = malloc(sizeof(Car*) * VEHICLES);
memcpy(cars_cpy, cars, sizeof(Car*) * VEHICLES);
```

`cars_cpy` remains its original order while `cars` is being sorted.

Comment: I feel like a goofus, thank you. I totally forgot about memcpy. I think this is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to preserve the original, you have to copy it. And *memory copy* is better than accessing a file and reading its contents, which involves system calls.

For the question which sorting algorithm the best one is, do you really want to go there?

But for comparison: [Wikipedia: Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Or just use **qsort**, which is posix.